# Validade date in PreviewTextInput DatePicker

Tags: c#, validation, datepicker

I have a DatePicker and a problem in PreviewTextInput event.
I need to include the "/" digit when length is 2 for days and 4 for months.

So, after input goes to 12 for example, i need to include "/" to keep "12/", but if i do that, the text reset and goes for another date.

```
private void dpDataEmissao_PreviewTextInput(object sender, TextCompositionEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((dpDataEmissao.Text + e.Text).Length == 2)
            dpDataEmissao.Text += e.Text + "/";

        if ((dpDataEmissao.Text + e.Text).Length == 4)
            dpDataEmissao.Text += e.Text + "/";
    }
```

The final result must be: "12/04/2017" and user need only put "12042017" and "/" will be included automatically.

Someone already get this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using a TextBox:**

You need to set `e.Handled` to `true` an adjust the position of the cursor:

```
if ((dpDataEmissao.Text + e.Text).Length == 2)
{
   e.Handled = true;
   dpDataEmissao.Text += e.Text + "/";
}

if ((dpDataEmissao.Text + e.Text).Length == 5)
{
   e.Handled = true;
   dpDataEmissao.Text += e.Text + "/";
}

if (e.Handled)
{
   dpDataEmissao.CaretIndex = dpDataEmissao.Text.Length;
}
```

**Using DatePicker: (Not that nice)**

```
private void dpDataEmissao_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (new int[] { 2, 5 }.Contains(dpDataEmissao.Text.Length))
    {
        InputSimulator.SimulateTextEntry("/");
    }
}
```

InputSimulator is part of: [Windows Input Simulator](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)

**PS:**

Don't forget to change the 4 to 5!

Comment: Hello! Thanks for help. I forgot to mention that i'm using WPF Datepicker, and i dont have CaretIndex property. Anyway, thats dont work too, after i set any text in Text property, the value changed to DateTime.Now

Comment: It's because of a System.FormatException in mscorelib.dll.

You can check the "Common Runtime Exceptions" CheckBox in the "Exceptions Settings" tab for more information.